# After Kovri arrives will some full nodes need to remain on clearnet?

Tags: kovri, p2p, peer-discovery

After Kovri arrives will some full nodes need to remain on clearnet?

How would peer discovery work if all full nodes suddenly converted to I2P for both inbound and outbound connections?

If most nodes move to Kovri, but a small number remain on clearnet would the remaining clearnet network become more susceptible to DDoS attack?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There will be three [modes](https://getmonero.org/design-goals/):

- I2P only: all traffic goes through I2P
- Clearnet only: all traffic goes through clearnet
- I2P/clearnet bridged: blocks go through clearnet, transactions go through I2P

Since everyone will not be able to use I2P, it will be necessary that some nodes run in mixed mode to avoid the network partitioning. Since the blocks aren't secret, they're a good match for clearnet (faster, which helps miners avoid orphans). Transactions benefit more from privacy, since you can't tell where a transaction originates (which would give a large network adversary a fairly good clue to which node(s) could have created it).

Answer (score 7):

Yes. I think exchanges and such will probably want to remain on clear net. This will require some nodes to operate as "bridge" nodes that will route information between clear and i2p networks.